# How does elasticsearch sort the document with the same score?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch6.8 and I get a list of document in the response. Some of the document have the same score but they appear on the same order in the response list consistently. I wonder what the algorithm ES uses to sort the document with the same score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES uses the index order when there is a tie when sorting on score.

The index order is defined by [the `_doc` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-sort).

Comment: Just to add to the above answer. In the linked docs, there's also noted that sorting doesn't have to be consistent when paginating. Thus, it's advised to additionaly always sort on some other unique field (e.g. timestamp the document was updated) to get consistent sorting.